# Spoilers Vs Search engine

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I first wrote [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5556) with a this title :

> Why Obi-Wan and Yoda disappears when they dies while Qui-Gon and Vader don't?

Then I step back and reformulated it by replacing the character names with the more generic "*Some Jedi*" and added spoiler markup in the question text.

The only problem is that I think the new spoiler-less question title would be less reachable though search engines, such as Google, since the first reflex is to use the names of the character in the search query.

So, what should we prioritize: a spoiler free environment or question titles that better match what people with the same question would be searching for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So long as you put the question somewhere there, even inside the spoiler protection markdown, it should be good enough to make the question searchable. Try to make it clear from the title what you are asking for anyone who knows, and that should be good.

So:

> Why some Jedi disappear when they die while others don't?

was a perfect choice.